# Постраничная навигация с большим количеством данных

Tags: mysql, pagination, постраничный-вывод, sql

Например, у меня есть БД с 10 млн записей. Мне нужно дать возможность пользователям/поисковым_ботам просматривать их все, разбив на страницы, и ссылка при этом должна выглядеть так: **http://example.org/content?page=100500**

Структура таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `contents` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  /* некоторые поля скрыты */
  `update_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', /* INDEX */
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Примерный запрос:

```
SELECT ... FROM contents WHERE ... ORDER BY update_time DESC [LIMIT ...];
```

Как можно реализовать **быструю** разбивку на страницы, не используя LIMIT OFFSET в данных условиях?

Comment: Что значит "не использовать LIMIT и OFFSET"?

Comment: @maxswitcher, БД в любом случае для поиска этих данных придется пропускать N первых записей. Тут два варианта - кэширование (которое постоянно будет инвалидироваться, поэтому это полумера) либо работа с серваком БД (обновление, работа на уровне оптимизации бд/таблиц, замена самого движка).

Comment: И посмотрите еще [шардинг](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture))

Comment: @msi, если использовать LIMIT OFFSET, например, `SELECT .. FROM ... LIMIT 10000, 5`, то он "перешерстит" ~10005 записей, а только потом вернет 5.
@Etki, даже не знаю, как можно это оптимизировать. Выборка с одной таблицы, индексы проставлены, но на таком количестве записей все равно сильно заметна разница между открытием первой и последней страницы.

Comment: @maxswitcher, для этого вам нужна консультация с хорошим DBA, но я как минимум привел выше в пример шардинг, плюс можно тупо перенести БД на ssd, если это еще не сделано.

Comment: @maxswitcher, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Я поступил следующим образом, у меня есть отдельная таблица, в которой хранится количество записей по каждой из рубрик. Таким образом, мы не нагружаем БД для подсчета записей, для последующей их разбивки, при каждом переходе на следующую страницу, а берем уже целое число и делим его на количество выводимых записей, получая при этом количество страниц.

В самом phpMyAdmin создать события, которые, допустим, раз в час будут делать подсчет количества записей и обновлять их в другой таблице, если сайт слишком активный и туда добавляется записи на постоянной основе.

Comment: @Palmervan, таким образом можно узнать общее количество страниц, но как брать данные для "далеких" страниц не используя LIMIT OFFSET, и при этом сохранив вид страниц типа url?page=100 ?